# Django Language didn't switch in template

Tags: python, django

all. I have some problems with language switching in the very simple application:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'lr.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^auth/(?P<cmd>.*)$', auth, name='auth'),
    url(r'^i18n/(?P<lang>.*)$', i18n, name='i18n'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

views.py

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    """
    Template view for Home page
    """
    template_name = 'home.html'


def home(request):
    """
    Site title page
    """
    return HomePageView.as_view()(request)


def i18n(request, **kwargs):
    """
    Change locale processing
    """
    from django.utils.translation import check_for_language

    if 'lang' in kwargs:
        lang = kwargs['lang']

        if lang and check_for_language(lang):
            if hasattr(request, 'session'):
                request.session[LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME] = lang

    if request.method == 'POST' \
            and 'redirect' in request.POST:
        # Place hidden input, named 'redirect' in login form in html template
        # for making redirect to the same page after login/logout
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST['redirect'])

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Page template is empty, it's just title, login form and ru/eng switch form (only three words for translate).

Somehow, language code (get_current_language) in template is always 'en', except when I place 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware' in top of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES - in this case he's always 'ru'.
I'm tried use django.conf.urls.i18n, translation.activate() and many other things, but no avail. Tell me some one, please, what's I'm done wrong?

Whole project code available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7nojxpxpajcbmu/lr.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a LANGUAGES setting.

> The list is a list of two-tuples in the format (language code, language name) – for example, ('ja', 'Japanese'). This specifies which languages are available for language selection. See Internationalization and localization.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#languages

Comment: Although this could be a good answer, it would be better if you copy-paste the relevant parts on your post. Links may get broken over time. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for answer, But I'm not missing LANGUAGES

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', u'Рус.'),
    ('en', u'Eng.'),
)

here is whole simple project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7nojxpxpajcbmu/lr.zip?dl=0